# Bellman optimality equation does not allow random policies?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, bellman-equations, game-theory

I'm reading the Sutton & Barto's book `"Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction" (2nd Edition)`. There is something I don't understand (p.63):

> Intuitively, the Bellman optimality equation expresses the fact that the value of a state under an optimal policy must equal the expected return for the best action from that state:
> [image]

This suggests that in a given state, there is an optimal action that *is not* "take a random action between 3 actions". However, this is the case in the `rock, paper, scissors` game where the Nash Equilibrium is obviously `play one of the three with equal probability` otherwise you are a target for exploitation.

Why is the Bellman optimality equation not taking this into account by just replacing pi by pi* in the Bellman equation:
[image]

With this, I could say that the optimal policy is to play action `rock` with probability `1/3`, `scissors` with probability `1/3` and `paper` with probability `1/3`.

Comment: You might be conflating Markov decision processes, where Bellman equation characterizes an optimal solution, and game theory, where different solution concepts (such as Nash equilibrium) are relevant.

Comment: Isn't reinforcement learning bound to converge to a nash equilibrium through self-play though?

Comment: Perhaps, though I have to say I have a hard time understanding how the Bellman equations in your question relate to that. As I recall the Sutton & Barto book also heavily focuses on the MDP setting rather than game theory, so some clarifying edits to the question might be needed.

Comment: Oh in a MDP setting there is a set opponent who cannot try and exploit you, right? So no need to not be exploitable?

Comment: Yes, MDPs are often referred to as "games against nature". The "opponent" is not actively choosing the worst outcomes for the agent, any uncertainty is packed into the next state-reward distribution $p(s',r|s,a)$ and the policy is optimized with that in mind.

Comment: I see. I confused both. Thanks! I’m currently at chapter 6 of Sutton and Barto but my goal is to learn to build agents that learn through self-play. Should I start reading other resources or are the basics of games against nature important to learn games against other opponents trying to exploit the main agent?

Comment: In my subjective opinion, understanding the MDP can certainly make it easier to make the leap to game theory, but you can't get all the way there only studying the Sutton & Barto book. I think what you are aiming at eventually are partially observable stochastic games. MDPs are a special case, as shown in the [nice diagram here](http://rbr.cs.umass.edu/camato/decpomdp/overview.html).